# Where do you download the C++ software?

Tags: c++

I am trying to learn a new language(for me) which will be c++. When I learned java in highschool I was told where to go to get a java Jdk and I downloaded bluej to create, compile, and run my programs. Where do you guys suggest I download these things for c++? I want to know where I can download a thing so I can create, compile, and run my programs for C++. I have windows 7

Comment: Install Linux (maybe in a virtual machine) and be free to use a lot

Comment: I'd start with an online service, like [IDEOne.com](http://www.ideone.com), at least for simple things. Google C++ compilers and you're get about a million hits.

Comment: http://nuwen.net/mingw.html is a pretty good mingw distro. It comes with git and a bunch of libraries to get you started.

Comment: [CodeBlock](http://www.codeblocks.org/) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 4):

For Windows, you can use visual studio express for windows desktop, with integrated interface and (limited) debugger:

http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads#d-express-windows-desktop

For Linux, you can use gcc on the command line

Comment: Linux: gcc or clang, with vim, emacs, Eclipse, Qt Creator, netbeans and whatnot. The command line is as optional as it is on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

DEV C++ is very effective and widely used.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/orwelldevcpp/files/Setup%20Releases/Dev-Cpp%205.5.1%20MinGW%204.7.2%20Setup.exe/download

Open this link and download the file. Installation will take place automatically.